# Condition On WHERE Clause

Tags: oracle

I need to add a condition on the WHERE clause such that when sevnum is not null then relate the tables by premnum and sevnum. However, the code below returns an error.

```
SELECT *
FROM prem c, tempTable t
WHERE 
  CASE WHEN t.sevnum IS NOT NULL 
     THEN t.premnum = c.premnum
     AND t.sevnum = c.sevnum
  END
;
```

Comment: What should the check be when `t.sevnum IS NULL`?

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE (    t.sevnum IS NOT NULL 
       AND t.premnum = c.premnum 
       AND t.sevnum = c.sevnum) 
/* OR (t.sevnum IS NULL) */
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not have a boolean type so the `CASE` expression you have - while it is standard SQL - returns a boolean value so it will raise an errror in Oracle.

Solution is to use `AND` / `OR` instead:

```
WHERE 
      t.sevnum IS NOT NULL 
  AND t.premnum = c.premnum
  AND t.sevnum = c.sevnum
```

which is equivalent to this (because you can't have `t.sevnum = c.sevnum` and `t.sevnum IS NULL` at the same time):

```
WHERE 
      t.premnum = c.premnum
  AND t.sevnum = c.sevnum
```

---

Besides that, I'd write the query using SQL-92 syntax with `JOIN`, instead of the implicit joins you use. The result will be the same but this syntax allows more flexibility when you want to have outer joins:

```
SELECT c.*, t.*
FROM prem c
     JOIN tempTable t
     ON
          t.premnum = c.premnum
      AND t.sevnum = c.sevnum
;
```